# A constructor that takes object from same type

Tags: c#, generics, types, constructor, clone

So I want to create constructor for my class `EmployeeNodeClass` that takes In `EmployeeNodeClass` object and copies it using a deepclone funtion:

```cs
public static T DeepClone<T>(T obj)
{
 using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
    ms.Position = 0;

    return (T)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
 }
}
```

to the new object.

At first i thought that it is as simple as

```cs
 public EmployeeNodeClass(EmployeeNodeClass EMPND)
  {
   this = DeepClone(EMPND);
  }
```

but then I got the error that `this` is readonly.

so how can I do it?

Comment: Serializing like that will **NOT** guarantee a deep clone if your type has reference type members.

Comment: What is the declaration of the `ThisEmployee` member ?

Comment: @OlivierRogier sorry, wrong constuctor. edited it

Comment: Never write "this = something" ! You have no right to change the current instance reference... So it is readonly. It is the compiler and the CLR that manage this special reference.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn It was SO top answare for how to create deepclones. If you have better methoud, can you send it to me please?

Comment: Do you _have_ to use a constructor to make your clone? Reassigning `this` is not allowed, but you could have a static method of your class that builds a cloned instance or a clone instance method.

Comment: @OlivierRogier yes I know this is why I ask how it can be done...

Comment: @AvivVetaro There's _**nothing**_ built into .Net to guarantee simple deep clones of complex types. You have to know your type and copy the fields. `IClonable` was meant to help with this, but has failed in practice.

Comment: Do'n use a constructor.  Make a static method that return T.

Comment: @Jacob I want to change to properties in one of  ```EmployeeNodeClass``` subclasses but I need to origin to remain the same so they cant point to the same location is memory

Comment: @AvivVetaro It can't be done. The compiler should refuse to compile a this assignment.

Comment: @jdweng how can I do it codewise?

Comment: @jdweng I think I get what you say...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using NewtonSoft JsonConvert.PopulateObject:

Example:

```
class Entity
{
    public List<int> List { get; set; }

    public Entity(List<int> list)
    {
        List = list;
    }

    public Entity(Entity original)
    {
        string originalJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(original);
        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(originalJson, this);
    }
}
```

And using it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var entity1 = new Entity(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 });
        var entity2 = new Entity(entity1);
        entity1.List[0] = 5;
        Console.WriteLine(entity2.List[0]);
    }
```

Note: since this uses NewtonSoft Json, it will only clone public, writable properties. So internal state in private fields (that are not associated with such properties) will be lost.